# Catalog Price Rules discount applied to Parent Category, not reflecting on Children

Tags: magento-1.9, category, sales, catalog-price-rules

Note:  I've asked this on StackOverflow, and will update my question there with credit (or delete) if I get an answer here.

I have have nested products which are not getting a discount if that product does not have the parent category selected within the product page. For example:

Within the Magento Admin, I've created a Catalog Price Rule "If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE : Category > contains > 8" (8 being the ID of the *Products* category) like so:

- **Products** - (20% Catalog Price Rule applied)

  - **T-Shirts**

T-shirt #1 has the "T-shirts" and "Products" category selected. Sale works fine.

T-Shirt #2 has *only* the "T-Shirts" category selected, leaving the "Products" category unselected.  Sale doesn't work.

You would think that the sale should still apply to all products of a subcategory even if the parent is not selected, because technically it's still a within the parent category.

If there is no way around this, I'm assuming I'd have to assign the "Products" category to all subproducts?  What If i have hundreds, is there a quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically you question may be right matching your requirement, but we can't say its an ideal condition.

consider this, Suppose the website is divided in different categories say, Apparels contain subcategory T-shirts which contains another child category SALE. Now i want to apply discount only on product under SALE category. In this case auto applying the discount on all parent category is not an ideal solution.

Technically while create a promotional rule you are applying discount to category Id which is unique so naturally the discount will be applied to that particular category. There is no in built functionality in Magento to auto assign discount to Parent Category too. So to achieve this you have to follow the approach stated below in screenshot.

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for explaining this with your example scenario- which does make sense, However I'm still not fully understanding because I feel that when you apply a discount to the parent, it should trickle down to ALL it's children.  (Even if that child didn't have the grandparent category selected).  Why should you have to select Shirts, Shoes, Hoodies, Mens, Womens when they are technically all "Apparel"?  Wouldn't it make more sense to just apply a discount to Apparel?

Comment: Yes it does makes sense in your case, but with regret i have to say Magento doesn't support this functionality by default. You either have to go the above mentioned way or will have to tweak the promotional rule logic.